# Telerik MVC Grid: Row specific content in a HtmlAttributes

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, html, html-title

Is it posible to use row specific content into HtmlAttributes?

I got this cell with its content `(o.ArrivalTime)`, when i move my mouse over it i'll like it to show the content from a other element `(o.Note)` in a tooltip

I tried this but it will not accept the `o.Note`

```
columns.Bound(o => o.ArrivalTime)
  .Title("Arrival Time")
  .Template(o =>
        {%><%=(o.ArrivalTime < Convert.ToDateTime("2000-01-01")) ? "?" : o.ArrivalTime.ToString()%><%})
  .Width(140)
  .HtmlAttributes(new {title = o.Note })
  ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using HtmlAttributes, you can do this inside Template.

```
columns.Bound(o => o.ArrivalTime)
  .Title("Arrival Time")
  .Template(o =>
    {%><div title="<%= o.Note %>"><%=(o.ArrivalTime < Convert.ToDateTime("2000-01-01")) ? "?" : o.ArrivalTime.ToString()%></div><%})
  .Width(140)
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following example.

[Grid - Server Templates](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/templatesserverside)

In this example the first column uses a templating mechanism to create the column. In similar way you can create a template for your column and then use the different columns while defining the template. Here is the code snippet from the demo:

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns => 
    {
        //Template column. The grid displays the HTML defined by the argument.
        columns.Template(c => {
        %>
            <img 
                alt="<%= c.CustomerID %>" 
                src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Grid/Customers/" + c.CustomerID + ".jpg") %>" 
              />
        <%
        });
        //Regular databound column. The grid displays the value of the CustomerID property.
        columns.Bound(c => c.CustomerID);
    })
    .Render();
```

%>

Hope this was helpful to your question.

Lohith (Tech Evangelist, Telerik India)